# how to create a dummy with a date range?

Tags: r

I would like to create a dummy with date ranges for example:

a dummie from 03/15/2020 to 03/24/2020,

1 for the period prior to 03/15/2020,

0 for the period covered 03/15/2020 to 03/24/2020

2 for the period after 03/24/2020

```
dados <- dados %>%
mutate(data_trat = if_else(mês=03/15/2020 to 03/24/2020,1,0,2))
```

Comment: Can you show the format of `mes`. Do you need `dados %>% mutate(data_trat = cut(mdy(mes), breaks = as.Date(c("2020-03-15", "2020-03-24")), labels = c(1, 0, 2)))`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cut` on a `Date` class converted column

```
library(dplyr)
dados %>% 
    mutate(data_trat = cut(mdy(mês),
       breaks = as.Date(c("2020-03-15", "2020-03-24")), labels = c(1, 0, 2)))
```

---

Or another option is `between` with `case_when`

```
dados %>%
    mutate(mês = mdy(mês), data_trat = case_when(mês < as.Date("2020-03-15") ~ 1,
      between(mês, as.Date("2020-03-15"), as.Date("2020-03-24")) ~ 0, 
      TRUE ~ 2))
```